# I have one div has Pleasewait image.It is not working normally.It works when i put alert after the method call

Tags: javascript

```js
function fnShowOpenImageProgressIndicator() {
  var updtPrgrssCtrlOpenImage = document.getElementByID("updateOpenImageProgress");
  updtPrgrssCtrlOpenImage.style.display = "block";
  setUserActionsLayerState(true);
}
```

```html
<div id="updateOpenImageProgress">
  <span class="round_span3"></span>
  <span class="round_span2"></span>
  <span class="round_span1"></span>
  <div class="content">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="SmartLabel12NavyBlueBoldItalic">syng</asp:Label>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/indicator.gif" AlternateText="Progress Indicator" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="SmartLabel12NavyBlueBold">&nbsp;opening images,
      <br />please wait...</asp:Label>
  </div>
  <span class="round_span1"></span>
  <span class="round_span2"></span>
  <span class="round_span3"></span>
</div>
```

Please wait is coming After i called fnShowOpenImageProgressIndicator method and followed by alert.

Without alert Please wait is not coming..

Comment: post your javascript code in a neat way. you can prefer this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview

Comment: I am making the div visble to show the pleasewait message to user.Pleasewait visible after calling fnShowOpenImageProgressIndicator method followed by alert. Otherwise not                                                                                   Please help me why it works when i use alert??                                           I want to use only javascript not jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the asp.net controls and instead try with HTML, JavaScript and CSS for such things. Using server side controls in this case, may not be preferred. Do something like this.

Add a div inside your HTML as:

```
{<div class="loadAnimation hidden"></div>}

{<div class="overlay hidden"></div>}
```

And add a css class for overlay as below for overlay:

```
.overlay 
    {
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%; 
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 10000; 
        top: 0px; 
        left: 0px; 
        background-color: black; 
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .loadAnimation 
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url(images/loading.gif);
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 500px 500px;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        z-index: 999999;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Open these div's accordingly and display in JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: Thanks for your answer